# System settings?

Tags: android, settings, system

I need to program an app to on powering on the device which is an htc tablet to control the wifi on and off setting and the gps on and off setting of the device. can an app control these and if so how i've never worked with system settings before? any educational pdf's,website's or youtube vidoe's would be great too. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

You can check it using

`boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()`

```
 wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
 wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
 wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

for `GPS`

Use this

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),    
Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
  }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),      
Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
  }
}
```